# apache2 inconsistent behavior with symbolic links

Tags: apache

I have two "identical" systems:

- Debian 12 (bookworm) with apache2 (2.4.57) and php8.2 (8.2.10)
- Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy) with apache2 (2.4.57) and php8.2 (8.2.10)

NOTE: I only mention php in this posting for completeness.

Setup and configuration:

- Both systems have the same enabled/disabled configurations, mods, and sites.
- Both systems have identical php.ini files.
- Both systems' /var/www/html directories have *identical* content and the same ownership/permission.

Inconsistent behavior:

- System (1) "Debian" will happily follow a symlink in /var/www/html that points outside DocumentRoot
- System (2) "Ubuntu" fails with `Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.`

Why? How do I "fix" system (2) "Ubuntu" so that it will follow *all* symlinks like system (1) "Debian" does?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!